# How to update a new version of Zend framework in the Zend studio

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-studio

I'm new to the Zend Studio and Zend framework. I'm trying to build a Zend framework project in Zend Studio. But the there is only one framework version could be selected, which I guess is the default one. If I want to add a new framework version and create a new Zend framework project with new one, how should do?

Thanks

P.S. The version of Zend Studio I used is 7.2.1 and the Zend Framework I want to add is version 1.11.3

Comment: I am trying to get version 2 to show up in the "Framework Version" section of the "New Zend Framework Project" window.  The only option that shows up in the drop down list is version 1.11.  It shouldn't be this difficult to make it so that version 2 showed up in this list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What [m0sc](http://#answer-4912086) said.

Another option would be to ignore the library zend studio uses; and just include it yourself everytime in the index.php:

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

I prefer to do it this way, because it's what I have to do in production anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The framework for zend studio is not compiled into a jar file.  ZF is a set of files in a resource folder.  All you have to do is copy the version of ZF you want to use with Zend Studio on top of the version that came with Zend Studio.

-- Former Zend Employee

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as far as i know. The framework is compiled into .jar file. The files however are stored in your workspace folder. So you could try updating them.

[workspace]/.metadata/.plugins/org.zend.php.framework.resource/resources/ZendFramework-1/library

But you can easily add a new library.

Window > Preferences > PHP Libraries

Here you can add a location to the new Zend Framework. And in your project you can attach this library.